# Working with items in a ComboBox and ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to move items back and forth between a ComboBox and a ListBox using C# 2010 (form)
My code seems to work. However, when I move the items back to the ComboBox (from the ListBox) I have a space in between the items.  If anyone has a suggestion on how to remove the space between the items in the ComboBox I would greatly appreciate it.

```
private void stateslistcomboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stateslistBox.Items.Add(statescomboBox.SelectedItem);
    statescomboBox.Items.RemoveAt(statescomboBox.SelectedIndex);
}

private void stateslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string item = "";
    item = Convert.ToString(stateslistBox.SelectedItem);
    statescomboBox.Items.Add(item);
    stateslistBox.Items.Remove(stateslistBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: This is not a practical UI design.  Use a "Remove" button to remove the selected item from the ListBox.  Also solves the Convert.ToString(null) problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `statescomboBox.Items.Add(item);` triggers Another `SelectIndexChanged` that adds an empty item.

Try

```
private void stateslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string item = "";
    item = Convert.ToString(stateslistBox.SelectedItem);
    statescombobox.SelectIndexChanged -= stateslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    statescomboBox.Items.Add(item);
    statescombobox.SelectIndexChanged += stateslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    stateslistBox.Items.Remove(stateslistBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

alternatively, you can prevent empty items being added.

```
private void stateslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string item = "";
    item = Convert.ToString(stateslistBox.SelectedItem);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)
    {
        statescomboBox.Items.Add(item);
        stateslistBox.Items.Remove(stateslistBox.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Infiniti68 please mark this post as your answer by clicking the tick  on the left of it,if it is your solution.